# Angular ngFor reading subarrays into list-items

Tags: angular, typescript

I am building a mat-list with mat-list-item. I am having problems with reading the subarrays into my list UI control. It shows up blank. For the part of the collection that does not involve subarrays, it shows up but the data in the subarrays are not incorrectly read with my ngFor angular code.

I googled and tried changing the ngFor code. I moved it between the mat-list and mat-list-item tags but the UI shows empty cells.

The collection Sale has a weekending string, which I can display without problem. I set the ngFor to loop thru days of saleWeekdays so I can read thru each day array collection. Within each day collection, I want to accces the metric to display the value string and the subCategory array, which I will need to add another *ngFor loop.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are accessing your json incorrectly:

```
"let day of saleWeek.days"
```

will give you this part of your json:

```
{ day: [] }
```

If you want to access the value, you need to iterate twice:

```
"let days of saleWeek.days"
"let dayInformation of days.day"
```

Where the `days.day` part will access your day array.
Then you can access your value:

```
{{dayInformation.value}}
```

Check out this jsfiddle for an example implementation:
https://jsfiddle.net/9o48jqty/

Comment: Hi, I change my code according to your advice but still empty cells:                                                                  <div fxLayout="row" fxFlex="9%" fxFlex.gt-sm="9%"  *ngFor="let days of saleWeek.days">
                <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex  >
                    <mat-list class="wf-list" >
                       

<mat-list-item fxLayoutAlign="end" (click)="onRowClicked(value)"  *ngFor="let dayInfo of days.day"><span>{{dayInfo.value}}</span></mat-list-item>



                    </mat-list> 
                </div>
            </div>

Comment: You will still need to iterate over they saleWeeks. So, if you 3 nested arrays, you need iterate all of them:

 *ngFor="let saleWeek of sales"
 *ngFor="let days of saleWeek.days"
 *ngFor="let dayInformation of days"

Comment: I did. 1st div is the ngFor="let saleweek of sales"> In the sub div I added ngFor="let days of saleweek.days". Inside this subdiv, I added mat-list-item with let dayInfo of days.day.

Comment: Thank your for taking your time to answer my issue. Again Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use another ngFor to get the inner loop values.

You cant get values from the following code. So **don't use** the following code

```
   <mat-list-item fxLayoutAlign="end" (click)="onRowClicked(value)" *ngFor="let day of saleWeek.days"><span>{{day.value}}</span></mat-list-item>

                        </mat-list>
```

You can **use** the following code **instead**:

```
<div class="sub_container"  *ngFor="let subsaleWeek of  saleWeek.days "> 
<mat-list-item fxLayoutAlign="end" (click)="onRowClicked(value)" *ngFor="let day of subsaleWeek.day"><span>{{day.value}}</span></mat-list-item>

                    </mat-list> 
</div>
```

Comment: Cheers Up !! @c0micrage

Comment: Thank your for taking your time to answer my issue. Again Thanks.